# ¿Por que no me funciona el do-while al validar una respuesta con equalsIgnoreCase?

Tags: java

Quiero validar una respuesta en java con un metodo, pero ocurre algo conla condicion del do-while ya que no es capaz de salir del bucle.

```
    public static String siNo() {
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
    String respuesta;
    do {
        System.out.print(" > ");
        respuesta=in.next();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Estoy detro del metodo  "+respuesta);
    } while (!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || !respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

    return respuesta;
}
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira que en tu condición tienes un "o", representado por estos símbolos  "||", por tanto, sí se cumple cualquiera de las condiciones, va a devolver true, no solo va a evaluar !respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que han concurrido para que se haya hecho tremendo problema.

El primer factor es la elección mismo de `do ... while`,  en cuyo caso se sale del bucle cuando la condición es `false`.

Luego, las evaluaciones al revés.

### Solución 1: Si quieres que salga al escribir una `S` o una `N` sin importar que sean mayúscula o minúscula

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String respuesta;
    boolean bolStatus = true;
    do {
        System.out.print(" > ");
        respuesta = in.next();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Estoy detro del metodo  " + respuesta);
        bolStatus = (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
        System.out.println(bolStatus);

    } while (!bolStatus);

    /*Cerrar scanner*/
    in.close();
```

**Prueba:**

```
debug:
 > e

Estoy detro del metodo  e
false
 > d

Estoy detro del metodo  d
false
 > s

Estoy detro del metodo  s
true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

---

### Solución 2: si quieres lo contrario

Sólo le quitas el `!` a la evaluación del `while`:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String respuesta;
    boolean bolStatus = true;
    do {
        System.out.print(" > ");
        respuesta = in.next();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Estoy detro del metodo  " + respuesta);
        bolStatus = (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
        System.out.println(bolStatus);

    } while (bolStatus);

    /*Cerrar scanner*/
    in.close();
```

**Prueba:**

```
debug:
 > s

Estoy detro del metodo  s
true
 >  n

Estoy detro del metodo  n
true
 > N

Estoy detro del metodo  N
true
 > S

Estoy detro del metodo  S
true
 > P

Estoy detro del metodo  P
false
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Analicemos tu sentencia:

```
while (!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || !respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
```

veamosla por partes:

Aca`!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S")` estas preguntando si respuesta es igual a `S` (obviemos el tema de mayusculas y minusculas). y estas transformando esa respuesta en la contraria. por lo tanto, cuando ingreso una `N`, esto devuelve `falso`, que como lo estas negando, es `verdadero`, o sea que nos quedamos dentro del loop.

Para la otra parte, `!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N")`, tenemos el mismo problema. Si ingresamos algo distinto de `N`, esto devuelve `verdadero`.

O sea que es todo un problema de logica, vos queres estar adentro mientras no se cumpla ni que sea n y s. por lo tanto, deberias hacer algo como:

```
RESPUESTA != S AND RESPUESTA != N
```

y la tarea para el hogar, es traducir eso (ten en cuenta que || es OR y && es AND

Answer (score 2):

El bloque `do..while` ejecuta un grupo de sentencias mientras se cumpla una condición.

La condición de parada que has definido es `!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || !respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N")`. Aplicando el [Álgebra de Boole](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_de_Boole) la expresión es equivalente a:

```
!(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

Como es imposible que la respuesta tenga al mismo tiempo dos valores distintos, la condición siempre se cumplirá y el bucle no terminará... nunca.

Si lo que quieres es que pare cuando se dé una respuesta distinta de `S` ó distinta de `N`, puedes utilizar la siguiente condición:

```
do {
// ...
} while (!respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && !respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
```